# "MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION does not exist", but it EXIST

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, percona

I use mysql to store users documents.
Any user have individual data base(sharding) in MySQL instance.

For store document in user db, I call from java procedure:

```
CALL `user_14890`.`createDocument`(...)
```

Inside this procedure, I call function:

```
DECLARE v_b_doc_uuid BINARY(16) DEFAULT `uuid.to_binary`(p_doc_uuid);
```

Sometimes I catch Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION user_14890.uuid.to_binary does not exist
```

Its impossible! Function exist!
After a few seconds, the function works fine. As if nothing had happened.

I use:

```
* MySQL: Server version: 5.5.55-38.8-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 38.8, Revision 11f5bbd
* java version "1.8.0_131"
* mysql-connector-java: 5.1.42
```

Please help! I can't catch this error in my local tests

Comment: Is the stored procedure the only place where the function (`\`uuid.to_binary\``) is called?.

Comment: No. Sometimes I use it in query `INSERT INTO \`user_14890\`.\`indexes\` (...,doc_uuid,...) VALUE (..., \`user_14890\`.\`uuid.to_binary\`(),....)`

Comment: And I have other procedures, what use this function

Comment: Do you always use the backtick (`\``) when calling the function (`\`uuid.to_binary\``)?.

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: Thing is, that created procedure, with call of `\`uuid.to_binary\`` function can generate error or not. When I get error, I retry this document and not error catched! Document created.